# dereferencing a char* always gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, operating-system

I am trying to go over the memory addresses and see different accessibility of the contiguous memory areas, which are: read-only, read&write and no accessibility. I also have a signal handler that takes care of segmentation fault so the program can continue running.

```
char* currentAdd;
char readBuf;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 0xffffffff, i+=PAGE_SIZE){
    currentAdd = (char*)i;
    jmpVar = sigsetjmp(env,1); // don't worry about this, it's handled properly

    if(jmpVar == 0){
    currentMode = MEM_RO;
    readBuf = *currentAdd; // always a segmentation fault
    
    // it can never try writing!!
    currentMode = MEM_RW;
    *currentAdd = readBuf;
    }
    else{
    ...
    }

}
```

my program never goes past (readBuf = *currentAdd;), which is sometimes expected but not always. Did I do something wrong?

I tried to start from i=1, to prevent what some people suggested but still it keeps giving me the segmentation fault.

Comment: Are you really surprised that dereferencing NULL segfaults?

Comment: For i=0 no, it's expected but not the rest of them.

Comment: Why not?  Location 1 is next door and so in the same page, with the same permissions/protection:(

Comment: What OS are you using? If Linux, look at `/proc/$PID/maps` to see what's actually mapped in. There's no need to try and determine this empirically, when the OS will just tell you.

Answer (score 0):

well you start your loop at i = 0, and then give currentAdd the address of a char at the address i, so currentAdd is basically (void*)0, aka NULL, so you are deferencing NULL, and no computer really like that.

Comment: But that's only for i=0, how about when I increment it, it should not give segmentation fault always.

Comment: I did but it's the same, the issue is with something else.

Comment: you will always get a segfault if you try to access memory outside what your program has requested, like if you declare an array of 10 int, if you try to acces the 11th one, it will segfault.

ok not always, but pretty much all the time.

Comment: @Bamontan That's not true. In fact, many times your program *won't* segfault, because the memory *is* mapped into the process (at 4k page granularity).